# Im trying to kill the sidebars but i cant - wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to setup a custom page, you can take a look here:

http://dageniusmarketer.com/download-the-book-now

and im using this code for my custom page. The sidebars as far as i can tell have IDs of "navigation", and "sidebar", however, the rules i am applying to them are not working.  I tried a test rule with the ID "content", and it works as expected. Why am i not able to hide the sidebars? Something isn't making sense.

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: My Custom Page
 * Description: A Page Template with No Sidebars.
 */
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>
<!--single.php-->
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post">
  <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
      <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>



  <?php the_content(); ?>
  <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
  <p class="metadata">
     <?php printf(__('%1$s %2$s', 'mtsgossip'), $time_since, get_the_time(__('l, F jS, Y', 'mtsjourney')), get_the_time()); ?>,
     <?php _e('by ','mtsjourney');?> <?php the_author();?>
    <?php _e('and is filed under','mtsjourney'); ?> "<?php the_category(', ') ?> ". 
  <?php if (('open' == $post-> comment_status) && ('open' == $post->ping_status)) {
    // Kommentare und Pingen erlaubt ?>
    <?php _e('You can','mtsjourney'); ?> <a href="#respond"><?php _e('leave a response here','mtsjourney'); ?></a>, 
    <?php _e('or send a','mtsjourney'); ?>
    <a href="<?php trackback_url(true); ?>" ><?php _e('Trackback','mtsjourney'); ?></a>
    <?php _e('from your own site','mtsjourney'); ?>.
<?php } elseif (!('open' == $post-> comment_status) && ('open' == $post->ping_status)) {
    // Nur Pingen erlaubt ?>
    <?php _e('Responses are currently closed, but you can send a','mtsjourney'); ?>
    <a  href="<?php trackback_url(true); ?>" >
      <?php _e('Trackback','mtsjourney'); ?></a>
    <?php _e('from your own site','mtsjourney'); ?>.
<?php } elseif (('open' == $post-> comment_status) && !('open' == $post->ping_status)) {
    // Kommentare geschlossen, Pingen erlaubt ?>
    <?php _e('You can','mtsjourney'); ?>
    <a href="#respond">  <?php _e('leave a response here','mtsjourney'); ?></a>. 
    <?php _e('Pinging is currently not allowed','mtsjourney'); ?>.
<?php } elseif (!('open' == $post-> comment_status) && !('open' == $post->ping_status)) {
    // Kommentare und Pings sind nicht erlaubt. ?>
    <?php _e('Both comments and pings are currently closed','mtsjourney'); ?>. 
    <?php } edit_post_link('E','',''); ?>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="navigation" style="margin-left:200px;"></div>
<div id="sidebar" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="content" style="width:900px"></div>

<!--postend-->

<p class="navigate">
  <?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link') ?>
  ||
  <?php next_post_link(' %link &raquo;') ?>
</p> 
<?php endwhile; endif;?>



<!--post end-->
<!--single.php end-->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the page structure, I tried to remove left and right sidebar by adding following styles. 
Put the following styles as inline css in the desired template, so that it don't affect the layout of any other page. Hope this helps.

```
div#navigation
{
   display:none;
}
div#sidebar
{
   display:none;
}
div#content
{
   margin: 5px 0 75px 0;
}
```

Comment: im not getting any result with this method unfortunately.  Is there a particular place i should put my code in the file?

Comment: This was it....but i had to figure out after much frustration that i needed to enclose it all within a <style></style> tag

Answer (score 0):

Your sidebar is being called with this line:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

You can try commenting it out to hide the sidebar:

```
<?php //get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: thats not what im going for, as the sidebar is being called by the footer too. What you just suggested messes up the page.  I just want to remove only the left and right sidebars.

Comment: Why is your sidebar being called by your footer? Just curious.

Comment: for the widgets.  My theme didn't have them originally, so i had to put them in. widget areas are specified as sidebars in the themes.

Answer (score 0):

You have two divs with the "sidebar" id, the one we can see in the code you posted (Which has the styles) and the one that eventually gets created by `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>`

These are not the same elements, so to fix your problem just remove that superfluous sidebar and apply the styles in your stylesheet.

Comment: not working for me. Lets disregard the sidebar id for the moment, why isnt the navigation id disappearing then? its the only id of its kind

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you delete all the content of sidebar.php? so, all other files that call it will show nothing.

Comment: not a suitable solution.  We're still not understanding why content works, but sidebar and navigation fail.  Thats what bugs me the most

Answer (score 0):

your sidebar is being called with this line

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

try to comment it

Comment: What do you mean by "this line"? Why should one comment code instead of removing it?